# Add a function as a parameter in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Imagine that I want to create a function called "execute()". This function takes the name of another function and its input as parameters and outputs whatever it returns.

Here is an example:

```
execute(print, "Hello, World!") # "Hello, World!"
execute(str, 68) # "68"
```

Of course, this function wouldn't be of any use, but I want to grasp the main idea of putting another function in as a parameter.
How could I do this?

Comment: In python everything is an object, so it can be passed as an argument to a function. There is a nice lecture about [functions being first class objects in python](https://realpython.com/lessons/functions-first-class-objects-python) on real python. I suggest you check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions can easily be passed into functions. To pass a variable length argument list, capture it with `*args` in the function definition and when calling the func use the same syntax to expand the arguments again into multiple parameters.

```
def execute(fn, *args):
  return fn(*args)
```

Note: we are not passing the *name* of a function to `execute()`, we are passing the function itself.

Comment: Thank you! Stackoverflow says that I can accept your answer in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this,

```
def execute (func, argv):
    return func(argv)
```

```
execute(print, 'test')
```

returns `test`

```
execute(str, 65)
```

returns `'65'`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```py
def execute(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

#### Here:

- args = Arguments (list)
- kwargs = Keyworded Arguments (dictionary)

If you want to do more, then you can look for [Decorators in Python](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/).

Comment: What is the difference between *args and **kwargs (I mean the * and the **)?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can pass functions as parameters into another function.
Functions that can accept other functions as arguments are also called higher-order functions.
I hope the following example helps:

```
def shout(text): 
    return text.upper() 

def greet(func):
   greeting = func("Hi, I am created by a function passed as an argument.") 
   print(greeting)

greet(shout)
```

The output of the code will be :

> HI, I AM CREATED BY A FUNCTION PASSED AS AN ARGUMENT.

Comment: Should you add the parameters in the greet function too?